# "Resolve Package Not Found" error in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda, spacy

I installed anaconda in Windows and then I wanted to add this code

```
conda env create -f robotreviewer_env_local.yml
```

but I got this error

> ResolvePackageNotFound
>     - spacy=0.101.0
>     - ptyprocess=0.5.1

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest that you erase those packages from the .yml file and then, activate the environment. Once there try `conda install spacy=0.101.0 ptyprocess=0.5.1`  or, if conda is unable try  `pip install spacy=0.101.0 ptyprocess=0.5.1 `

Answer (score 2):

## General Strategies

#### Search for Channels

Try searching in [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/) for the specific packages that can't be resolved. Sometimes they might be from channels other than **defaults** (**anaconda**). Include your platform (e.g., `platform:win-64`) in your search to narrow things down faster. If you find a channel that has it, then you can add it to the **channels** section of the YAML definition.<sup>**1**</sup>

#### Check PyPI

If you can't find Conda channels with the versions you need, head to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) and search there. If you find them, move them to the **pip** section of the YAML.

#### Remove the Requirements

If you know where to find the packages in source, then remove them from the YAML, and install them locally in the activated environment.

#### Loosen the Versions

If you don't have a super strict reproducibility concern, you can always remove the versioning (minor, major) to get one that you can install from Conda or PyPI.

---

<sup>**1** Of course, if you aren't familiar with the channel source, verify that it's not some malicious code before using it. E.g., download the tar.bz and scan it.  I haven't heard of any such attacks, but this seems like an obvious vector.</sup>

---

## Specific Resolution of Packages

#### Spacy

Searching the Anaconda repo shows that neither [the anaconda (defaults)](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spacy/files?version=0.101.0) nor [the conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spacy/files?version=0.101.0) channels have that Spacy version available for win64 platform.  However, there is a dedicated spacy channel, which could be where it was originally obtained. So, in the **channels** section of the YAML, you could add

```
channels:
  - spacy
```

#### ptyprocess

This package is not found anywhere in Anaconda Cloud, but it is on PyPI, so you should move it the **pip** section of the YAML file:

```
pip:
  - ptyprocess=0.5.1
```